# tail -f starting with the entire file

Tags: tail

I would like to follow a file but `tail -f` always starts with the last 10 lines. Is there a way to output the entire file then follow?

My goal is to find all occurrences of a string in a log, such as `tail -f streaming_log | grep "string"`. But also include all previous line.

I know I can do `tail -f -n 10000 file` but I don't want to count the lines first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`-n +<line>` allows you to specify a *starting* line (`1`-based):

```sh
tail -f -n +1 file  # output entire file, then wait for new content
```